# Unable to release connection from mysql after some time in spring boot application

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, datasource, jdbctemplate

I am using Jdbc template and DataSource to connect mysql.

the configuration that I am using is given in application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://hostname/databasename
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=1
```

And My Main Class in Which all configurations are called is below:

```
package com.es.producer;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

import com.es.producer.config.Config;
import com.rabbitmq.jms.admin.RMQConnectionFactory;

@EnableWebSecurity
@SpringBootApplication
@SpringBootConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.es.producer")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableSwagger2
public class EsProducerApplication {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    JdbcTemplate template;
    EsProducerApplication() {
    }


    @Bean
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {

        RMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new RMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setUsername(Config.getRabbitmqusername());
        connectionFactory.setPassword(Config.getRabbitmqpassword());
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(Config.getRabbitmqvhost());
        connectionFactory.setHost(Config.getRabbitmqhost());
        return connectionFactory;

    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate connection(){

        return template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(EsProducerApplication.class, args);

    }
}
```

and The Controller class is below:

```
package com.es.producer.controller;



import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.es.producer.EsProducerApplication;


@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Controller
public class DBTOQueueController {

    JdbcTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Autowired
    EsProducerApplication esProducerApplication;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        template =esProducerApplication.connection();

    }



    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @CrossOrigin

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/senddata")

    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendDataQueue(
            @RequestHeader("tableName") String tableName) throws JSONException {

        try {

            String selectSql = "select * from " + tableName;
List<Map<String, Object>> employees = template.queryForList(selectSql);
// doing some operations

}}
```

when I am starting my spring application  and after one minute if I try to terminate my application then connection with sql gets released.But if the application is in running state for more minutes and trying to terminate it the termination takes place but the connection is not released from  mysql.

Any  Help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: How are you doing the jdbc operations? You shouldn't inject the configuration class instead you should `@Autowired` the `JdbcTemplate`. `@EnableAutoConfiguration` on your controller doesn't add anything, just remove if. Also `@SpringBootApplication` already implies `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@ComponentScan` and `@SpringBootConfiguration`. Next to that Spring Boot already creates a `JdbcTemplate` so you don't need to create one yourself.

Comment: I have modified the controller class in which the jdbc operation are mentioned.